# JNI -> Convert null terminated cstring to jstring

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to convert a C-style string to JString using UTF-8 encoding. I am aware of the NewStringUTF method which does this. But, the input c-style string might not always be UTF-8 encoded. Therefore the runtime would crash if I pass a non-UTF-8 c-string to this method.

I planning to convert it to byte array and then build the jstring from that. Is there a constructor that returns a default (or) empty jstring if the given byte array does not confine to UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: [CharsetDecoder.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) would throw an exception if that's good enough for your needs...

Comment: There's not much point in converting a byte array into a `String` when you don't know the encoding.  `String` has a deprecated constructor which uses the platform default file encoding, but if you truly expect to get non-ASCII and non-utf8 encodings, you're not likely to get anything useful in the `String`.  Ideally you'd require an indication of the encoding on the input side.

Comment: The runtime would crash only if you didn't clear the exception before calling other JNI functions. But, anyway, NewStringUTF doesn't take UTF-8, it takes _modified_ UTF-8.